# Is a try except statement equivalent to execute or execute other?

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch

Try statements are new to me, so is a `try except` statement equivalent to execute or execute fail code?

This is how I see it in bash:

```sh
cmd || otherCmd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try-except statement is a code block that allows your program to take alternative actions in case an error occurs. Python will first attempt to execute the code in the try statement. If no exception occurs, the except statement is skipped and the execution of the try statement is finished. If any exception occurs, the except statement will trigger. This way your program handle exceptions instead stopping.

Comment: I know, I’m asking if it’s the equivalent of: do this or if that doesn’t work do this

Comment: to my knowledge, I think yes!